# Registers saved on stack in system_call

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

When system_call function is called, it supposed to check some arguments and call the function pointed from the system calls table according to the argument passed in eax. This is the part that saves the registers:

```
system_call:
pushl %eax
SAVE_ALL
movl $0xffffe000, %ebx /* or 0xfffff000 for 4-KB stacks */
andl %esp, %ebx
```

Why it saves the eax twice? (in the command pushl %eax and in the macro SAVE_ALL which saves eax as well).

Comment: What file(s) are you looking at specifically and what version of linux?

Comment: Linux 2.6 I think, it's from a slide from tutorial about system calls.

Answer (score 2):

The standard C calling convention on x86-32 uses `%eax` to return a value from a function. Linux syscalls also pass back their return value to userspace in `%eax`. How is this done on x86-32?

The syscall entry point in `arch/x86/entry/entry_32.S` calls a syscall handler function, then *overwrites* the stored value of `%eax` (the one stored by `SAVE_ALL`) on the stack with its return value. Later, when returning back to userspace, the stored values of all the registers are popped off the stack into the registers. Since the `%eax` value stored by `SAVE_ALL` was overwritten with the desired return value, when the user code resumes execution, naturally it finds the syscall's return value in `%eax`.

But there are times when the kernel needs to find the *original* saved value of `%eax`. Even if the value saved by `SAVE_ALL` has already been overwritten, it can still look at the value saved by the first `pushl %eax`. In the kernel code, this value is called `orig_eax`. (Grep the kernel source and you will find it in a few places.)

Look at the `RESTORE_REGS` macro in `arch/x86/entry/entry_32.S` and you will see it takes a `pop` parameter, which is used to adjust the stack after popping all the saved register values back into the registers. You will find `RESTORE_REGS 4` just at the point where a syscall is returning back into userspace. That "4" is there to get rid of the value pushed by the `pushl %eax` which you asked about, also known as `orig_eax`!